# Unexpected ASCII-8BIT encoding in response of the POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, nginx

I have a the following API method in my rails app:

```
 # -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
 def statistics
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        render json: Lead.scope1.scope2, root: false
      }
    end
 end
```

And standard ActiveModel::Serializer for Lead model:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
class LeadSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :external_id, :external_ip, :fio, :phone, :city, :region, :lead_status, :spl_status, :description, :created_at, :traffic_source, :ad_company, :amount, :product_id

  def attributes
    data = super
    data[:phone] = Digest::SHA256.base64digest(object.phone.to_s).truncate(15)
    data
  end

end
```

I have `config.encoding = "utf-8"` in my `application.rb` and

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

in my `environment.rb`. I also have specified default encoding `utf-8` in `nginx.conf`.

When I call `Lead.scope1.scope2.to_json` from rails console on production server the encoding of the response is `UTF-8`.

But for some reasons when I try to call `statistics` method from ruby script using `curb` the encoding is `ASCII-8BIT`. Here is the script.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'curb'
curl = Curl::Easy.http_post("#{uri}",
             Curl::PostField.content( ...**... ),
       ) do |curl|
           curl.ssl_verify_peer = false
           curl.ssl_verify_host = false
end

curl.perform

p curl.body.encoding

#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your `Curl` request will return a response in whatever encoding the web server chooses to use. If the encoding could not be determined correctly you might have to `force` the correct encoding upon the body, but you should check this. Is the content of your object ok?

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I can use `force_encoding`, but how can I make web server to provide me `utf-8` encoding by default? I am using unicorn.

Comment: You probably would not want to `force_encoding` unless what you get *is* UTF-8 already (which it probably is not, so you will have to convert it). In order to get an UTF-8 reply you will have to tell your *Client* to request it from the server. From what I can tell from the [`curb` documentation](http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html) this should be possible with `easy.encoding = string`, maybe you can ask for `easy.encoding` to see if it would allow `ASCII-8BIT` by default and how to specify your desired encoding.